# ValueError: Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs) on tensorflow keras version

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have the following error when I'm trying to fit the model: ValueError: Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` for more information of where went wrong, or file a issue/bug to `tf.keras`.

If I understood correctly there is something wrong with the size. The code for this:

```
H = model.fit_generator(
    trainAug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=32),
    steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // 32,
    validation_data=valAug.flow(testX, testY),
    validation_steps=len(testX) // 32,
    epochs=args["epochs"])

# evaluate the network
print("[INFO] evaluating network...")
y_score = model.predict(testX, batch_size=32)
print(classification_report(testY.argmax(axis=1),
    y_score.argmax(axis=1), target_names=lb.classes_))
```

I got this error

```
train.py:154: UserWarning: `Model.fit_generator` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use `Model.fit`, which supports generators.
  epochs=args["epochs"])
Epoch 1/80
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 154, in <module>
    epochs=args["epochs"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2223, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1395, in fit
    raise ValueError('Unexpected result of `train_function` '
ValueError: Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` for more information of where went wrong, or file a issue/bug to `tf.keras`.
```

how to resolve this error for more code details [CLICK HERE](https://github.com/OmRajpurkar/Alert-Generation-on-Detection-of-Suspicious-Activity-using-Transfer-Learning/blob/main/videoClassification/train.py)

Comment: A good first step is try what the error message suggests - insert tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True) before running, you may get some more meaningful error messages.